# Why is '-Di' not the default for a 'p4 integrate'?

Tags: version-control, perforce

Imagine the following scenarion: we have two perforce-managed directories: trunk and branch.

1. File1 is added to branch and then integrated to trunk
2. File1 is renamed File2 on the branch
3. a new File1 is added to the branch

In this case, the default integrate from branch to trunk will not contain File1, until the integrate is committed and a second integrate will then pick up the change.

This problem can be circumvented by doing the integrate with the -Di option. My question is: why is this option not the default? Does it lead to problems elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  A good example of how -Di might be problematic is the case where File1 has been edited on the trunk and/or branch.

Suppose that the old File1 contains "A", trunk/File1 is "AB", and branch/File2 is "AC".  Suppose the new File1 is "D".

```
branch/File1: D
branch/File2: AC
trunk/File1:  AB
```

If you do the default integrate, you start by merging branch/File2 with trunk/File1, which both merges the content (producing "ABC") and then moves trunk/File1 to trunk/File2.  The follow-up integrate branches branch/File1 to the now-vacant spot on trunk, so trunk/File1 becomes "D".  This is the ideal outcome.

If you do the integrate with -Di, you branch branch/File2 to trunk/File2, giving you a trunk/File2 with content "AC", and you do a baseless merge between branch/File1 and trunk/File1, with "AB" on one side and "D" on the other.

So in summary, with the default (two step integrate) you get:

```
trunk/File1: D          (branch)
trunk/File2: AB+AC=ABC  (clean merge)
```

With the -Di (one step baseless integrate) you get:

```
trunk/File1: D+AB=???   (baseless merge)
trunk/File2: AC         (branch)
```

In theory you can sort this out by resolving the conflict, picking through the history manually, noticing that the B change should be in another file, and then manually editing it into File2.  You're likely to end up having to repeat this performance when integrating into other branches (and now it's complicated by the fact that the connection between File2 and File1 is less obvious).